# Scrapy loop through txt file of words for url format

Tags: python, scrapy

lets say i have this spider:

```
class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ExampleSpider'
    start_urls = []

    def parse(self, response):
        for res in response.css('div.example'):
            item = {
                 'example' : res.css(examplehere)
            }
            yield item
```

Is there a way that i can have starturls = ["examplesite.com/{}/search"]
then loop through my text file of words and format it so for example something like: starturls = ["examplesite.com/{}/search".format(i for i in txtfile.txt)] and this way it would scrape through all the urls for the words i have in the text file? Im not sure if this can be done in scrapy please let me know the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was asked before.

Use [start_reuqests](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=start_requests#scrapy.Spider.start_requests) method:

```py
import scrapy


class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ExampleSpider'

    def start_requests(self):
        with open('spiders/urlFile.txt', 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                url = f"https://examplesite.com/{line.rstrip()}/search"
                scrapy.Request(url=url)

    def parse(self, response):
        for res in response.css('div.example'):
            item = {
                'example': res.css('examplehere').get()
            }
            yield item
```